# How can I find the file containing the code selecting the pin for a Google map in Wordpress?

Tags: html, wordpress

I'm displaying a Google map in my Wordpress site using the Qode Tours plugin, and I want to change the pin to a custom one. There is no option within the plugin to change the pin of the map, so I want to find the file to edit this. I can see the piece of code selecting the pin:

[image: code selecting the pin]

I downloaded via FTP the whole plugin folder and scanned it via bash (on Mac) looking for the string `data-pin`:

```
egrep --color -R 'data-pin' *
```

but it's not there. I found a `location.php` file with a string `'custom_map_style' => 'yes',`. Is there a way to find out where it's taking parameters from?

Comment: The code that handles the pin will be inside Google Maps API. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @LeeTaylor I edited the question; I want to change the pin to a custom one. Where can I find the code you mention, in the google cloud developer console?

Comment: Just swap out `themes/bridge/img/pin.png` with your custom image.

Comment: @DavideL https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial There are also methods to change the pin inside the API. Although, yes, you can change the image it might be a good idea to learn what's going on inside.

Comment: @LeeTaylor thanks, I agree and always like to learn what's actually going on. But it's also good to have an effective solution like the one in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you own the server that image is hosted on... go find the image in the server using the path you have highlighted, and change it via FTP or SSH/RSYNC

so go into this folder on your server

```
/wp-content/themes/bridge/img/
```

download the image `pin.png` so you know the dimensions it is expecting, then change the image to whatever you want it to be, then reupload it with the same name, essentially overridding it. Now when your plugin references that pin, it will use your new image.

*NOTE - once you do this, the original image will be lost forever, so you may want to dupe it and rename it to something like `pin_legacyOriginal`

**NOTE - make sure to clear your browser cache when checking for the new image.